# How do I correctly bind a component to refresh when a value is updated?

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have a simple application that purpose is to fetch the current weather for a location.  That location has a default, but one of the components have buttons that should change the location, call the API, and then re-display the data.

So I have two components: Location and WeatherDisplay.  I also have a Service that does the heavy lifting (basically calling the API).

My problem is that the WeatherDisplay doesn't change when the user clicks on a new location.  I'm a beginner towards Angular, so let me know if I leave something out in this "presentation."

I have tried a number of different things and I think I have narrowed it down to something in the API Service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { WeatherStruct } from './weather';

const API_URL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather';
// my key for the OpenWeatherAPI
const API_KEY = '3f25...'; // deleted most of what my key is just 'cause
// default location
const LOCATION_ID = '4480285'; // Morrisville, NC
// get the value from the message

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class APIService {
    private locationSource: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    currentLocation = this.locationSource.asObservable();

    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private msgService: MessageService
    ) {}

    getWeather(loc_id = '4480285'){
        // this.msgService.add('api.service.ts '+loc_id);
      console.log('api.service getWeather('+loc_id+')');
      const api_string = `${API_URL}?id=${loc_id}&APPID=${API_KEY}&units=imperial`;
      console.log(api_string);
      return this.httpClient.get(api_string);
  }

    changeLocation(locid: string) {
        console.log('api.service changeLocation('+locid+')');
        this.locationSource.next(locid);
        // need to tell weather-display to re-fetch the data
        this.getWeather(locid);
    }
}
```

in the location component template I have:

```
<button (click)="newLocation('5391811')">San Diego, CA</button>
```

the weather-display component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from '../message.service';
import { WeatherStruct } from '../weather';
import { APIService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-weather-display',
    templateUrl: './weather-display.component.html',
    providers: [APIService],
    styleUrls: ['./weather-display.component.css']
})

export class WeatherDisplayComponent implements OnInit {
    weather: WeatherStruct;
    private today: number = Date.now();
    loc_id: string;

    constructor(
        private apiService: APIService,
        private msgService: MessageService
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.currentLocation
            .subscribe(location => this.loc_id = location);
        this.fetchWeather();
        console.log('CCC');
    }

    fetchWeather(loc_id = '4480285') {
        console.log('weather-display.component showWeather(' + loc_id + ')');
        this.apiService.getWeather(loc_id).subscribe((data: WeatherStruct) => {
            this.weather = data;
            this.weather['today'] = this.today;
        });
    }
}
```

and in the location.component.ts:

```
export class LocationComponent implements OnInit {
    location: string;

    @Output() talk: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor(private apiService: APIService,
        private msgService: MessageService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.currentLocation.subscribe(
            location => (this.location = location)
        );
    }

    newLocation(newLoc: string) {
        console.log('location.component newLocation('+newLoc+')');
        // use an event emiitter 
        this.talk.emit(newLoc);
        // call a function in the service
        this.apiService.changeLocation(newLoc);
    }
}
```

and lastly in the app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    location: string;

    constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

    title = 'The Weather';

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.currentLocation.subscribe(
            location => (this.location = location)
        );
    }
    goGetWeather(newLoc){
        console.log("app.component.goGetWeather("+newLoc+")");
    }
}
```

When I execute my app and try to click on a button, I see the code execute like I expect it to:

**location.component newLocation()** is called, which calls
**app.component.goGetWeather** [which tells me the event emitter is working]; and 
**api.service changeLocation**, which leads to 
**api.service getWeather** which produces the correctly formatted API string to call

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2643743&APPID=3f25...&units=imperial
```

but nothing changes in the DisplayWeather component.

I know its something simple, but I just can't put my finger on what it wrong.

Comment: Just a note: when you aim to understand, go with simpler examples and add more type signatures to your code.

Comment: Can you add the source code for DisplayWeather component.

Comment: Added the display-weather component (which is actually named WeatherDisplay, mea culpa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be achieved by using shared service. Refer to the link on how to implement shared service: http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/09/angular-share-data-between-components.html

This is how the code will look like:

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    // Subject (emitter) for User Name Change
    CityNameChange: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    // SetUserChange() - This method sets the local variable and emits the change
    SetCityChange(param: string) {
        this.CityNameChange.next(param);
    }
}
```

in your first component on click of button where city changes call the service.setCityChange()

```
this._sharedService.SetCItyChange(newCityName);
```

In your second component, in ngOnInit subscribe to the city Change event and get the weather data based on the new city:

```
this._sharedService.UserNameChange
  .subscribe((value) => {
    // Get the weather information
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got your problem correctly, the data is not flowing properly. You can fix this by using more RxJS. Take a look on how I would implement this.

```
// Dont use any inside your source code, use an type alias while you are working dirty instead. 
type Location = any;
type Weather = any;


// The name is not really correct anymore, it is more a WeatherLocService.. 
@Injectable()
export class APIService {

  defaultLocation = {
    // .. or handle the cases where currentLocation emits null anyhow. 
  };

  // Holds the current location
  private currentLocation$ = new BehaviorSubject<Location | null>(null);

  // Holds the weather at the current location
  weatherAtLocation$: Observable<Weather>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {

    // Whenever location changes, call getWeather with the new location and return the result 
    this.weatherAtLocation$ = this.currentLocation$.pipe(  
      mergeMap(location => this.getWeather(location))
    )
  }

  getWeather(location: Location = this.defaultLocation): Observable<Weather> {
      return this.httpClient.get("https://www.example.com");
  }

  updateLocation(location: Location) {
    this.currentLocation$.next(location);
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-umqxpv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapi.service.ts